# Put two inputs to the same line

Tags: html, css

I would like to put two input to the same line.

I know that I could use `float: left`, but I have heard that, not recommended the usage of `float`.

I have tried `display: inline-block;` but this is not working.

```css
.d-input {
  display: inline-block;
}

.resize {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  display: inline-block;
}

.resize input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-input">
  <span class="resize">
    <input type="text"/>
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="click" class="sub"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `display: flex`. Check-out the below code

```css
.d-input {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.resize {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  display: inline-block;
}

.resize input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-input">
  <span class="resize">
    <input type="text"/>
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="click" class="sub" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution apart from `flex` would be to add `vertical-align: top;` on your `input[type=submit]`.

```css
.d-input {
  display: inline-block;
}

.resize {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  display: inline-block;
}

.resize input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-input">
  <span class="resize">
    <input type="text"/>
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="click" class="sub"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `display: inline-block;` statement on the input declaration instead

```
.d-input {
  display: inline-block;
}

.resize {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.resize input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or in the case you want two resizable inputs, keep your original CSS, but use this HTML

```
<div class="d-input">
    <span class="resize">
        <input type="text"/>
    </span>
    <span class="resize">
        <input type="text"/>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="click" class="sub"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Then they are not in the same line.

Comment: also removed the width: 100% from the inputs .. you could optionally add a bit of margin to the right too - `margin-right: 10px` etc

Comment: This way I cannot resize the first input

Comment: I have added a second solution, please just use the HTML above.

Answer (score 0):

you are working too hard!  Just get rid of everything you don't need

```css
input {
  overflow: hidden;  
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
  
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="click" class="sub"/>
```

Comment: This is remove my ability to resize the input

Comment: @palloc why is this an issue if the accepted answer loses the first inputs resize ability?

Comment: @カメロン  He/She just forget to add the rest of his/her css code. As you can see it is working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/locpal/upc12Lb9/). Unfortunatelly I cannot suggest an edit due to the fact that my suggest queue is full.

Comment: "They" should be sufficient. Thanks for clarifying, I will edit their post.